# Dynamic heightForRowAtIndexPath: with many (thousands) of cells

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I'm having some performance issues when using a dynamic value in `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` 
 (I know it's this method because if I set a static value the responsiveness increases substantially). My table contains around 3000 cells.

I understand why the performance suffers when using a dynamic value (mainly because the calculations in the method must be performed once for every cell in the table before the data can be shown), but I can't figure out how to make it more efficient.

In many of the similar questions I've come across, the proposed solution was to use `NSString`'s `sizeWithFont` method in `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` to speed things up. I currently do that but the table still takes roughly ~1.5sec to load (and reload, which is done somewhat frequently). This is just too long and I need to optimize it.

The code I'm currently using (the essence of it at least) is below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    UILabel *label = nil;

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        // set up label..
        [[cell contentView] addSubview:label];

    }

    NSDictionary *dict = alphabetDict; //dictionary of alphabet letters (A-Z). each key contains an NSArray as its object
    CGFloat rightMargin = 50.f; //padding for the tableview's index titles

    NSString *key = [[[dict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *array = [dict objectForKey:key];
    NSString *cellText = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //TABLE_WIDTH is 268.f, CELL_MARGIN is 14.f
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(TABLE_WIDTH - (CELL_MARGIN * 2) - rightMargin, 20000.0f);
    CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17] constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    [label setFrame:CGRectMake(CELL_MARGIN, CELL_MARGIN, TABLE_WIDTH - (CELL_MARGIN * 2) - rightMargin, labelSize.height)];
    [label setText:cellText];

    return cell;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //TODO make this faster

    NSDictionary *dict = alphabetDict;
    CGFloat rightMargin = 50.f;

    NSString *key = [[[dict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *array = [dict objectForKey:key];
    NSString *cellText = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(TABLE_WIDTH - (CELL_MARGIN * 2) - rightMargin, 20000.0f);
    CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17] constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    return labelSize.height + (CELL_MARGIN * 2) + 16.f;  
}
```

Could someone point me in the right direction to streamline this code further? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have faced this similar situation before. My solution is to do all the calculations and store the heights in an NSMutableArray called heightsArray before you do [tableView reloadData]. Then

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   [heightsArray objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
}
```

No calculations while scrolling up and down. Plain reading from the array. The initial hold-up will be more because of the calculation being done upfront but it is worth it in terms of performance gains while scrolling. You can also perform the calculation on a background thread thereby saving processing time. Just do all that in a method which you can call on a background thread and prepare your heights array.

Comment: Good suggestion, but this code assumes the table has only one section and that it won't be manipulated in any way (i.e. no cells will be added or deleted) - otherwise you would have to recalculate the heights every time that happened. But it is a clever trick nonetheless.

Comment: When you are deleting a cell, delete the corresponding height from the heightsArray. When you are adding a cell, do the height calculation and add it to the heightsArray. These should be relatively inexpensive operations I believe when compared with the original problem.

Comment: You're right. This works great. The initial load is a little slow but I'll entertain the user with an activity indicator. Scrolling and adding/deleting cells is very quick now. Thanks crypticcoder.

Answer (score 1):

The most time consuming part in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is:

```
[[[dict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
```

So, you can start by adding a property `sortedKeys` and use it like this:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *key = [sortedKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    CGFloat rightMargin = 50.f;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I implemented the change and it seems to have knocked a couple milliseconds off but the load time is still not where I want it to be. Any other suggestions? I can't possibly have made it as efficient as it can be?

Answer (score 0):

crypticcoder has a good suggestion. I would suggest a variation of that, which might be more flexible, and support table changes (insert, delete, reorder).

Create a class that is a subclass of UITableViewCell and add a cellHeight property adn ivar cellHeight_ to it. Synthesize it this way:

```
@synthesize cellHeight=cellHeight_;
```

Calculate the cell height in a lazy way with this code inside the class:

```
-(CGFloat) cellHeight{
    if (cellHeight_ != 0)
        return cellHeight_;
    else {
        NSDictionary *dict = alphabetDict;
        CGFloat rightMargin = 50.f;

        NSString *key = [[[dict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        NSArray *array = [dict objectForKey:key];
        NSString *cellText = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(TABLE_WIDTH - (CELL_MARGIN * 2) - rightMargin, 20000.0f);
        CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17] constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

        cellHeight_ = labelSize.height + (CELL_MARGIN * 2) + 16.f; 
        return cellHeight_; 
    }
}
```

Like sch, I don't like the sort in there, but if it's not really the performance problem, I'm leaving it there.

If you want to change the contents of a cell, make sure you reset cellHeight_ to zero so it is recalculated lazily (when it's needed again).

Comment: What do you mean by calculating lazily. Does it mean while scrolling or on the background thread or a new spawned thread?

Comment: Lazy calculation means the calculation is not done until the result is needed. This is a good way to avoid having a lot of configuration taking place in one block of time, but spreading the calculations out to happen when they are needed. (If they are needed all at once, then it is no better and no worse.) Once it has been calculated, it gets saved, in this case, as an ivar in the class. In my example, a vlaue of zero is used to indicate that the value has not been calculated. (I thought it would be safe to assume no cell height is zero.)

Comment: I made a mistake in the if statement. I'll correct that. (It should be `if (cellHeight !=0)`. I also for got the return statement for cellheight. I added that, too. I'm sorry if that caused any confusion.